# How to write query to select first event forever that matches given criteria

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I have stream of events like "page view"
- pageUrl
- timestamp
- ...

I need to select only "first" page view event for each pageUrl.
I know about ISFIRST but AFAIU it accepts time window as a mandatory parameter, but I need to filter first event "forever"

Answer (score 1):

> it accepts time window as a mandatory parameter

Yes, time window is required because all the aggregate function need a set of data during a period of time.

```
SELECT 
    pageUrl,
    timestamp
INTO
    MyOutput
FROM 
    Input TIMESTAMP BY Time
WHERE 
    IsFirst(minute, 60) OVER (PARTITION BY pageUrl) = 1
```

I suggest you create a job to query the first event for a period of time and export the data. You could query the exported data(MyOutput) to get the first page view event for each page URL.